# How can I use delegates to process text?

Tags: c#, delegates, parameter-passing

I am currently deserializing XML into an object "X" within a function processText().  I want to pass a function as a parameter, so that I can call processText and apply any arbitrary rules to the object X.  This seems like a case of using delegates, but I cannot figure out how to make use of them given the examples online...

To show example of what I have tried:

```
AiringProcessing ap = new AiringProcessing(localFiles[1]);
//  getZeroLengthAirings is the particular process I want to run during my text processing
AiringDelegate del = new AiringDelegate(ap.getZeroLengthAirings);
ap.processBatch(del);
```

Comment: Why don't you show what you have tried so far..

Comment: Added example.  I might be using poor design here, but I have several functions implemented in the AiringProcessing class that I'd like to use as operations during the text processing, and I want to be able to select any subset of them to be passed in to the processBatch function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To pass a delegate as a parameter you will want to use `Action<T>()` or `Func<T>` depending on the return values (Action returns void).

here is an example using action:

```
public void TakeADelegate(Action<string> action, string str)
{
  action(str);
}
```

Call it with a delegate:

```
this.TakeADelegate((string s) => { ... do work here ...})
```